# Delete, function remove, does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I followed this tutorial in a blog, its just a sample tutorial using indexedDB. I'm new with indexedDB so I can only understand a little bit of it.

Other functions such as read, readAll and add is working properly. While function remove is not working. Those functions are called `onclick` through a button.

Whenever I click Delete data the button disappears and the nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="all">
  <title>Sample IndexedDB</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="read()">Read </button>
    <button onclick="readAll()">Read all </button>
    <button onclick="add()">Add data </button>
    <button onclick="remove()">Delete data </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
     //prefixes of implementation that we want to test
     window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

     //prefixes of window.IDB objects
     window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
     window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange

     if (!window.indexedDB) {
        window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.")
     }

     const employeeData = [
        { id: "00-01", name: "gopal", age: 35, email: "gopal@tutorialspoint.com" },
        { id: "00-02", name: "prasad", age: 32, email: "prasad@tutorialspoint.com" }
     ];
     var db;
     var request = window.indexedDB.open("sampleDB", 3);

     request.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("error: ");
     };

     request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        db = request.result;
        console.log("success: "+ db);
     };

     request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("employee", {keyPath: "id"});

        for (var i in employeeData) {
           objectStore.add(employeeData[i]);
        }
     }

     function read() {
        var transaction = db.transaction(["employee"]);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("employee");
        var request = objectStore.get("00-03");

        request.onerror = function(event) {
           alert("Unable to retrieve daa from database!");
        };

        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
           // Do something with the request.result!
           if(request.result) {
              alert("Name: " + request.result.name + ", Age: " + request.result.age + ", Email: " + request.result.email);
           }

           else {
              alert("Kenny couldn't be found in your database!");
           }
        };
     }

     function readAll() {
        var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");

        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
           var cursor = event.target.result;

           if (cursor) {
              alert("Name for id " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + ",\r\nAge: " + cursor.value.age + ",\r\nEmail: " + cursor.value.email);
              cursor.continue();
           }

           else {
              alert("No more entries!");
           }
        };
     }

     function add() {
        var request = db.transaction(["employee"], "readwrite")
        .objectStore("employee")
        .add({ id: "00-03", name: "Kenny", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" });

        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
           alert("Kenny has been added to your database.");
        };

        request.onerror = function(event) {
           alert("Unable to add data\r\nKenny aready exist in your database! ");
        }
     }

     function remove() {
        var request = db.transaction(["employee"], "readwrite")
        .objectStore("employee")
        .delete("00-03");

        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
           alert("Kenny's entry has been removed from your database.");
        };
     }
```

Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but there are a few things:

- You generally don't want to use for in over an array. For..in is for iterating over keys of an object. Use for(var i = 0; i < arraylength;i++) to iterate over an array.
- The brackets around the object store like in db.transaction(['store']) are optional. You don't need them. In fact you are using them inconsistently so your code is hard to read.
- You shouldn't be using the variable 'var db' in the way you are using it. The connection may be null or closed by the time you click Remove.
- Although you can, I would recommend not inserting data from within the onupgradeneeded function. The upgrade needed function is for creating or modifying your database schema. You should instead be using some other function.  By directly calling that other function, indexedDB will determine automatically if it needs to call onupgradeneeded first and then execute your function.
- You don't need the prefixes like `window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB ...` anymore. All major browsers that support indexedDB dropped these prefixes.  Just use `window.indexedDB`
- Not sure why you are handling request.onerror in only some of your functions
- You don't need to prefix global variables with 'window'. For example, you can directly use `indexedDB` instead of `window.indexedDB`.
- You generally don't want to call 'alert' from within the context of readAll's function that iterates a cursor over the store. alert is blocking. The cursor iteration is asynchronous.

Anyway, my best guess is that somehow the onclick handler for the button is calling `element.remove()` similar to `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)`.  Try renaming the remove function.

Also, try adding an onerror handler to remove, and also check that after you add, you can see the object in the object store in dev tools.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Your guess seems right and renaming it fixed it. Also, about my coding style, most of the codes were copy pasted from the tutorial and just trying it out myself. I'll take note of the things that you listed.